# python virtualenv cant seem to find modules even though they've already been installed

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to run my python app on my website, and so I've created a virtual environment for all of the packages, and I've correctly installed all of the packages I need. When I check on the file path to my installed packages, they are all pointing to the correct path, and when I got to my `site-packages` file that they point to, they are all there.

However,

Every time I try to run my app, I get this:

```
    stdin: is not a tty
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 369, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 76, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "/home/dsmproto/testblockchain/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    import main as application
  File "/home/dsmproto/testblockchain/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from wallet import wallet
  File "/home/dsmproto/testblockchain/wallet.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
ImportError: No module named Cryptodome.PublicKey
```

I know that the module is there, but for some reason it is still saying there's no module.

Is there a command I can use in my SSH to check where my app is looking for modules?

All of the modules I have installed are installed correctly. Furthermore, when I open the SSH and run python commands in the terminal, they are able to import all of the modules without any issues.

So how come my app can't find these modules? Is there a way to check to make sure they are looking in the right place?

Thanks in advance for the help

EDIT:

I ran a script in python to look at the `sys.path` and got this:

```
    /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python38.zip
/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8
/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload
/home/dsmproto/virtualenv/testblockchain/3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages
/home/dsmproto/virtualenv/testblockchain/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Those are the correct folders that my packages are installed in, yet when I try to run my app, it still says it can't find them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  How are you running your app?

Comment: @ewong The app is able to run, but it just can't find the modules. I'm running it through that passenger_wsgi.py file, which points it to my main.py file, which runs the app. does that answer your question? Sorry, I'm really new to this stuff

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  If it can't find the modules, it can't run.   I mean how are you running passenger_wsgi.py?  I'm suspecting the environment you're running passenger_wsgi.py isn't the same environment that you have the modules installed in.

Comment: I'm confused too, because the environment I'm running my app on is the exact same environment I have the modules on too. I triple checked, and I even ran 'sys.path' to show me where it's looking for modules, and it's pointing to the correct folders. I'll update my question to show that too. But you're right the app doesn't run, but I know it tries to run until it can't find a module, and then gives me and error.

Comment: Please include exact details how your environment is set up and how the app is run. (possibly include the commands as well)

Comment: what exactly do you need to know about how it was set up? All I know is in the cpanel for my website I went to the "Setup Python App" section and followed the instructions to set up the virutalenv. what info do you need? I'll try to find it because i really need help with this

Comment: From the information provided,  I am guessing that the cpanel environment isn't using the virtualenv python binary; but using the system one.   I don't know anything about cpanel, but I'd suggest trying to setup the cpanel env to use the virtualenv's python binary

Comment: okay, ill try to figure out how to do that. Thank!